# I have completed 2 yrs of my PhD and I want to leave my toxic lab and transfer to a new one. How should I approach potential new advisors?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, europe, application-cover-letter, harassment

In my current position, my committee believes that I am by all metrics a successful student. I'm even working on two papers. But I've had to endure sexual harassment and working conditions that endanger both my life and the neighbouring labs'. My prof does little to address these issues and discouraged me from taking them further. I've gone to my dept and to the university ombudsman, but there are no official procedures for this so nothing happens. Additionally, of the 6 PhD students who have come before me in the lab, only 1 will be able to defend and both of the other women quit within 1 yr.

In cover letters I'm upfront about the fact that I'm switching programmes. But I'm afraid saying anything negative about my current lab to a new prof only reflects poorly on me so I only state that my research interests have shifted and my current lab doesn't have the resources to support that. I'm afraid this sounds hollow though. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Are you trying to move to a new lab/advisor at the same institution?

Comment: No, I'm trying to move to a new institution.

Comment: Okay.  Sorry, I don't have any relevant advice, and I am very sorry you have to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you are correct in assuming some people will view any and all conflicts with "authority" as stirring trouble and label it as undesirable. And yes, this may impact your application.

But ask yourself this - what are you willing to tolerate and why? Is sweeping the issue under the rug completely really the best approach here? If the new place does not view sexual harassment as a viable reason to change the workplace, will you want to work there?

It is true that academia is extremely hierarchical, and making your current professor fix their lab one way or another might be out of reach for you at this point in your career. But I would argue you should not avoid bringing up the real issue with the new lab. Your response to the situation was well-measured, you went through the official channels as any reasonable person would, and then decided not to escalate, which is not the only possible decision here, but it is a viable one nevertheless.

Stay factual. If you state "I have experienced X, and this makes the work environment unacceptable for me", and the new lab thinks it reflects poorly on you ("oh what a snowflake, everyone knows X is normal"), this is just another bullet dodged.

You may still press the charges, of course. But at very least, facing indifference should not be forcing you to keep your head down. Go, find a better place to be at.

Comment: So do you believe then that I should mention the harassment in a cover letter? I was hoping to discuss it in the interviews, should I get that far.

Comment: @ducks_unlimd Hmm. Interviews sound like a very reasonable choice for bringing it up indeed. But I would also say that citing "interpersonal issues" as a reason for changing a lab should not tank the application, either - if anything, a sensible committee would reserve their judgement until after the interview, which is a good outcome for you w.r.t. application/cover letter. No one likes divas, but if the way you write here is any indication, it is not really a concern. Being firm and professional with the boundaries is a virtue, and a short and upfront statement would do well on that front.

Answer (score 1):

First, I am sorry that you have experienced this. Second, I think you should get out of this situation, and you should do everything you can not to hinder your opportunity to find a job elsewhere.

Thus, I would not advise bringing up any interpersonal issues in an application letter. Already, when students change programs, there is often the question of whether they are doing this voluntarily or if they have been forced out of the program. Several people typically review these letters, so even if 90% are sympathetic, it might only take one person being skeptical or perceiving this as a "red flag" to remove you from the consideration list.

Even if they are 100% sympathetic, this can still count against you because it brings more uncertainty into the equation. Ask yourself: if Candidate A and Candidate B are otherwise equally great, why take a chance choosing the candidate who might bring interpersonal issues to the department?

I also think it's too risky to bring it up in the interviews. Keep in mind professors often know each other and may even be friends, so it's possible you could cause yourself more trouble (e.g., if you don't get the job and your interviewer tells your advisor that you are trying to leave and badmouthing their program). If you make it to the interview round, they want you there, so focus on making the best possible impression. If they ask, stick to your "change in interest" story and quickly change the topic to expressing your enthusiasm and ideas about said interest.

If all goes well, you can tell your new advisor the real reason after you've moved and built a trusting relationship with them. Good luck--my thoughts are with you.

Sincerely, someone who has fought a similar battle

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry you went through this and, as someone who was in a similar situation, I know making the choice to leave isn't easy so congratulations on deciding to leave a toxic work environment.

Approaching new potential advisors and talking about your experiences is indeed tricky so I'll share my experience in case it helps. Personally, I tried to keep it in a positive light for the cover letter and said I decided to leave the position to pursue a PhD that [insert skill/topic/goal you want to reach].

During the interview stage, everyone I interviewed with asked about it and I had a neutral answer ready. I did not talk badly about anyone but made it clear that a) it was my decision to leave and b) my issues were with the work environment and not the science. I would advise you to make sure potential advisors understand this choice wasn't about having a few bad results and deciding to change topics because you couldn't push through getting stuck on a problem (this would a good time to talk about the papers you're working on).

Regardless of what you write in the cover letter, you need to have an answer ready for the interview (and beyond) because everyone will ask about it. I think staying neutral/factual without giving too many details is your best bet at navigating this situation. Mentioning that other PhD students have recently quit and/or are not finishing their degrees is another way of letting people know there is a systemic issue with the lab and it's not just you without having to say it explicitly.

I wish you the best of luck and hope you find a nice PI and lab - they do exist!